# How do I add to a variable based on another variables value? (Python)

Tags: python

So I am making a game in Python, and have this bit of code as a function.

```
def playerDeploySoldiers():
    global error #a basic error, contect the creator message
    answer=1#tells the program when to stop asking
    while(answer==1):
        clearScreen()#just clears the screen
        printDeploySoldiers()
        #needed to define answerDeploySoldiers
        if(answerDeploySoldiers=="1"):
            deploySpot=sanitised_input("Where: ", str, range_=(playerCountries))
            deployNumber=sanitised_input("How many: ", int, 1, playerExtraSoldiers)
        elif(answerDeploySoldiers=="0"):#none of this matters
            print("You have finished deploying soldiers")
            answer=0
        else:
            print(error)
```

sanitised_input() is just input() but ensuring the player can't add something random like 'asdflasdf;jasdf' as their input. deploySpot will be equal to a country name. For every country, there is a variable called armies*CountryNameHere*. deployNumber is a positive integer.

I want to add deployNumber, an integer value, to armies*ValueOfdeploySpot* (armies*dploySpot*+=deployNumber), without having to put an if-statement for every possible country deploySpot could be. Is this possible?
For example, if deploySpot==USA (not actually an option but just to pretend), I would add the value of deployNumber (which could be something like 100 or 986) to armiesUSA (armiesUSA+=deployNumber). But I can't be sure that deploySpot==USA. It could be Mexico, Brazil, Russia, France, (none of these are actual options but they're examples), or any other country.

I have tried finding answers on stackoverflow, but came up with nothing I could understand or ever hope to with the keywords or similar questions I could think of. Most things involved creating a variable using another's value, using a differet language for something different, or something completely beyound my understanding.

For clarification, I am trying to avoid having to do this under deployNumber's value assignment.

```
if(deployNumber=="USA"):
    armiesUSA+=deployNumber
```

and having to do that for EVERY possible deploySpot value.

Comment: Sounds like you need to learn about *dictionaries*.

Comment: `I want to add deployNumber` ... are you saying that you want to do `armiesValueOfdeploySpot += deployNumber`? ...... or, are you saying that you want to associate `deployNumber` with `armiesValueOfdeploySpot`?

Comment: armiesValueOfdeploySpot+=deployNumber

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dictionaries in python can be assigned like so:

```
First_var = 0
Second_var = "hi"
MY_DICT = {First_var:Second_var}
# Reference like so:
Value = MY_DICT[First_var]
#Value now equals Second_var because it assigns the value of the first variable to the next.
```

I think this is what you are asking?
If you mean that you want the value to change based on another variable then add:

```
CONDITION = True
if(CONDITION):
   MY_DICT[First_var] = NewValue
```

I believe this should change the value assigned. Tell me if I am wrong

Comment: Sort of, if I made a dictionary containing all the countries and their armies, I would want to change the value of their armies. The problem would be that CONDITION would have about 12 different possible values/outcomes, as their are 12 countries in my game.
To be honest, I don't really understand this answer.

Comment: I'm trying to understand what you are asking then, I feel like dictionaries could work very well because you can change the values rather easily...

Comment: Just use += to MY_DICT[First_var] = NewValue and it should work fine

Comment: Ok I think I may have found an answer, I am trying it now.

Comment: Ok I tried something, and now it is shorter,but still pretty long. But at least it's not crazy long. I made a dictionary with every country's name and armies, the long part will be making every variable for armies*countryname* reset to its value in my dictionary.

Comment: Can't you use for loop? The theory behind: 
For i in dictionary:
   armies1 = dictionary[i]

Comment: by enumerating countries you have a shorter way of reading countries